# Why can't I use \DeclareMathOperator{\H}{\mathbb H}?

Tags: math-mode, macros, math-operators

Is there a reason why I cant use `\DeclareMathOperator{\H}{\mathbb H}`?

`\H` is not defined normally, so why can I define this?

`\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb R}` and others similar work just fine.

Comment: `mathbb` needs `amsfonts`. Also, it is strange to define  `\mathbb{R}` as a math operator. Maybe you want simply a `\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}`.

Comment: `\H: macro:#1->{\accent "7D #1}` is defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is fairly precise in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\H}{\mathbb H}
\begin{document}
$\H a$
\end{document}
```

Compiling the document gives:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \H already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.3 \DeclareMathOperator{\H}{\mathbb H}
```

which is telling you that `\H` is already defined.

There are also other single letter commands (e.g., `\A`). In general, it is better to avoid defining your own single letter commands. Instead use `\RR`, `\HH`, etc.

Also, as @Sigur pointed out, it does not make sense to define `\mathbb{R}` or `\mathbb{H}` as a math operator. It is better to use

```
\newcommand\RR{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\HH{\mathbb H}
```

etc.

Comment: It is sad that the cli does not tell us in which file \H is already defined. Is it safe to use renewcommand?